# Executing the string in each line of the test.txt file with skip_letter function?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, output, txt

I have test.txt file, each line of this file has a string. I want the `skip_letter` function to run for each string. I have 100 strings in txt file. I want output by running these strings one by one in function. I mean: I have a string named `banana` which is assuming it will be `bananna`. I just want the `bananna` to be output.

My code:

```
import itertools

def skip_letter():
    print("\nSkip Letter:\n")
    for combo in itertools.combinations(keyword, len(keyword) - 1):
        word = "".join(combo)
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the function a parameter instead of using the global variable `keyword`. Then call it when you loop over the file contents.

```
import itertools

def skip_letter(keyword):
    print("\nSkip Letter:\n")
    for combo in itertools.combinations(keyword, len(keyword) - 1):
        word = "".join(combo)
        print(word)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        skip_letter(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your function defined, you just need to read your txt file and iterate over each one of the lines. Beware that the skip_letter function now has a parameter `keyword` to let the function know which string needs to use.

```
import itertools

def skip_letter(keyword):
    print("\nSkip Letter:\n")
    for combo in itertools.combinations(keyword, len(keyword) - 1):
        word = "".join(combo)
        print(word)

file1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
  
for line in Lines:
    skip_letter(line)
```